# C# NUnit unit test not using correct method return to compare

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following class

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static double Converter(int mpg)
    {
       return Math.Round((double)mpg / ((double)36 / 12.74), 2);
    }
}
```

And NUnit unit test

```
[TestFixture]
public class ConverterTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Basic_Tests()
        Assert.AreEqual(8.50, MyClass.Converter(24));
    }
}
```

My Unit tests fails with

```
Expected: 8.5d
But was:  8.4900000000000002d
```

When I debug the method return 8.49 so where does the unit test get the long number from with a 2 at the end?

Comment: Where did you see the `8.50` result? The value before `Math.Round` call is `8.49333333333333` ([demo](http://ideone.com/7zwzh2)). By the way, you do not need the casts to `double`, because `12.74` is a `double`.

Comment: 1. I know before the rounding it is not 8.4900000000000002d. That is what is so confusing

Comment: @devc2: Before rounding it's 8.493333... - so it makes sense for it to be 8.49 after rounding - or the closest double to that value, which is 8.4900000000000002d. I'm *only* confused as to how you've ever seen it as 8.50.

Comment: Sorry mistyped. The debugger does show 8.49. I was thrown of by the 2 at the end that was returned by the unit test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit test shows the same result as I see when executing the code. Here's a short but complete program to show the *exact* result retrieved, using my [`DoubleConverter`](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) class.

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double x = Convert(24);
        Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(x));
    }

    static double Convert(int mpg)
    {
        return Math.Round((double) mpg / ((double) 36 / 12.74), 2);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
8.4900000000000002131628207280300557613372802734375
```

Using a calculator, I'd expect the unrounded result to be 8.4933333 - which would indeed round to "about 8.49" when rounded to two decimal places.

So really, the question is more why you're seeing 8.5 in the debugger than why the unit test fails. I'm not seeing that myself, so you might want to look into exactly how you're debugging. When you debug, you may be seeing different results because:

- In debug you may be using different floating point operations, e.g. "pure" 64-bit instead of the 80-bit intermediate operations which are permitted by .NET
- You may be debugging other code which sets the floating point mode of the processor to 32-bit; I've seen this happen when using DirectX, but I'd expect you to be aware that you're doing it
- The debugger may be *displaying* the results in a truncated form, although I wouldn't expect it to truncate that number to 8.5

Comment: Question is how do I change the function so the unit test passes? After rounding the watch in debugger for Math.Round((double) mpg / ((double) 36 / 12.74), 2) is 8.5

Comment: @devc2: Your unit test is asserting the wrong result - the result of that computation to 2 decimal places is 8.49. Why would you want to assert that it's 8.5? What *exactly* do you mean by "after rounding the watch in debugger"? You should explain *exactly* what you're doing in the debugger to see 8.5.

Comment: Sorry mistyped. The debugger does show 8.49. I was thrown of by the 2 at the end that was returned by the unit test

Comment: Thanks Jon, You have answered it. The debugger only showed 8.49 where the unit test error displayed 8.4900000000000002d.

Comment: @devc2: Well yes - because there's no double with an exact value of 8.49. If you `Assert.AreEqual(8.49, ...)` that should be fine - because the assertion will be comparing it with "the closest double value to 8.49". See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx if you're unsure of why that is.

Answer (score 1):

'double' is a *dirty trick* to manipulate fractions... :-)

You should NEVER test for equality when talking about doubles.

The *correct* way to test is:

```
Math.Abs(8.50 - MyClass.Converter(24)) < TOLERANCE
```

Where 'TOLERANCE' is how much variance is accepted.

Ex.

```
for TOLERANCE == 0.001
8.5004 == 8.50
8.4995 == 8.50

for TOLERANCE == 0.01
8.504 == 8.50
8.495 == 8.50
```